# Find character position and update file name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What function might I use to find a character position in a string using PowerShell 2.0?

i.e I would use CHARINDEX or PATINDEX if using SQL Server.

I looked at using the `Select-String` cmdlet, but it doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.

Ultimately I'm looking to find a "_" character in a file name and strip off everything to the following "." .

Example file name **237801_201011221155.xml**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The string is a .NET string so you can use .NET methods. In your case:

```
$index = "The string".IndexOf(" ")
```

will return 3, which is the first occurrence of space in the string. For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx

For your need try something like:

```
$s.SubString($s.IndexOf("_") + 1, $s.LastIndexOf(".") - $s.IndexOf("_") - 1)
```

Or you could use regexps:

```
if ($s -Match '(_)(.*)(\.)[^.]*$') {  $matches[2] }
```

(has to be adjusted depending on exactly what you need).

Comment: Also worth noting this syntax for a varible: e.g.
    `$path = get-location`
    `"$path".IndexOf("\")`

Answer (score 2):

If you use Excel, then the command would be Find and MID.  Here is what it would look like in PowerShell.

```
 $text = "asdfNAME=PC123456<>Diweursejsfdjiwr"
```

asdfNAME=**PC123456**<>Diweursejsfdjiwr - Randon line of text, we want **PC123456**

```
 $text.IndexOf("E=")
```

**7** - this is the "FIND" command for Powershell

```
 $text.substring(10,5)
```

**C1234** - this is the "MID" command for Powershell

```
 $text.substring($text.IndexOf("E=")+2,8)
```

**PC123456** - Ta-da! It has found and cut our text.

Answer (score 2):

If you split the filename on underscore and dot, you get an array of 3 strings. Join the first and third string, i.e. with index 0 and 2

```
$x = '237801_201011221155.xml' 
( $x.split('_.')[0] , $x.split('_.')[2] ) -join '.'
```

Another way to do the same thing:

```
'237801_201011221155.xml'.split('_.')[0,2] -join '.'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with actual files (as opposed to some sort of string data), how about the following?

```
$files | % { "$($_.BaseName -replace '_[^_]+$','')$($_.Extension)" }
```

(or use `_.+$` if you want to cut everything from the first underscore.)

Comment: cheers for the suggestions. I'll add the code to my ever growing Powershell toolbox

Comment: You're welcome. I do think `Get-Childitem *.xml | Rename-Item -NewName { "$($_.BaseName -replace '_[^_]+$','')$($_.Extension)" }` is easier on the eye than the .Substring/.IndexOf solution.

Answer (score 1):

I create a string object using the .NET String class to expose all the methods normally found if using C#:

```
[System.String]$myString
 $myString = "237801_201011221155.xml"
 $startPos = $myString.LastIndexOf("_") + 1 # Do not include the "_" character
 $subString = $myString.Substring($startPos,$myString.Length - $startPos)
```

Result: 201011221155.xml

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Solution by OP migrated from question to an answer:</sub>

> Final Solution, The below strips out all characters from and including
> <_> to <.> for all .xml files in the current directory
>
> ```
> Get-Childitem *.xml | Rename-Item -newname `
>   { $_.name -replace $_.name.SubString($_.name.IndexOf("_"), `
>        $_.name.LastIndexOf(".") - $_.name.IndexOf("_") ),''}
> ```
>
> Will end up with **237801.xml**