# Renaming files by removing parts of the filename

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to go through all the files within a folder and rename them so that the name becomes whatever is between the 2nd and 3rd `_`.

e.g.: `1_2_3_4.pdf` becomes `3.pdf`

Having looked around, I was able to find the link below which helps with a very similar issue - but I am unable to make it work for my specific issue. Would anyone minding helping with this?

[Find character position and update file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095782/find-character-position-and-update-file-name)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Martin. Out of interest, if I wanted to adjust your command to go from the 2nd "_" to the end of the file name,
e.g.: e.g.: 1_2_3_4.pdf becomes 3_4.pdf how would i do that?

Comment: Change the first literal: `'.*?_.*?_([^_]+).*'` to: `'.*?_.*?_([^_]+)''`

Comment: ahh, to `'.*?_.*?_([^_]+)'` no double single quotes at the end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all files and rename it using the `Rename-Item` cmdlet (together with a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) replace):

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\your_folder' | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1}' -f ($_.Name -replace '.*?_.*?_([^_]+).*', '$1'), $_.Extension }
```

Comment: some explanation would help. :), but its not me who downvoted that answer.

Comment: @4c74356b41 I wonder why you are complaining about explanation where basically the half of your answers is like "try this" or doesn't even explain anything. However, I explained which cmdlet I used and that I use regular expressions. I won't write a regex guide in my answers. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Still, what explanation are you missing? There are sites like https://regex101.com where you can copy paste the regex to get further information if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: well, i only said that because someone downvoted your answer, and that seems to be the only reason to downvote a proper answer.

Comment: For me the answer is complete and working so the downvote was either a mistake or just a troll.

Comment: There is a VTC on this so it is possible someone didnt want you answer a question where the OP showed little effort.

Comment: @Matt that might be the reason - even it doesn't justify a downvote: *"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"*, I know I shouldn't answer questions without effort but doing it time to time. In this case, he at least tried to find an exisiting answer on SO but wasn't able to adopt it. However, the downvote isn't a big deal for me, just odd.