# powershell extracting data from strings or other suggestions

Tags: powershell, replace, find, character

I have a script I am writing that essentially reads data from an excel document that is generated from another tool. It lists file ages in the format listed below. My issue is I would like to process each cell value and change the cell color based on that value. So anything older than 1 year gets changed to RED, 90+ days gets yellow\orange.

So after a bit of research, I elected to use an `if` statement to determine when it is greater than 0 years which seems to work fine, however when I reach the days portion I'm not sure how to extract JUST the digits portion to the left of `d` in each cell when you get to the `y` if its there just stop OR possibly just read the left digits only if the `$_` contains `d` then I could further process if that value is `-gt 90`?  I am unsure of how to extract variable length strings only if they are digits left of a character. I considered using a combination of the below method of finding a character and returning up to `y` or something else.

[Find character position and update file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095782/find-character-position-and-update-file-name)

Possible Age Formats:

- 13y170d
- 3y249d
- 8h7m
- 1y109d
- 1y109d
- 1y109d
- 5d22h
- 3y281d
- 3y184d
- 11y263d
- 7m25s
- 1h14m

  `[regex]$years = "\d{1,3}[0-9]y"`

  `[regex]$days_90 = "\d{0,3}[0-9]d"`

## conditionally formatting/coloring row based on age (years)

```
if ( $( A$_ -match "$years") -eq $True ) {
$($test_home).$("Last Accessed") | ForEach-Object { $( $($_.Contains("y") -eq $True ) { New-ConditionalText -Text Red } }
```

## conditionally formatting/coloring row based on age (90+ days)

```
if ( $( A$_ -match "$days_90") -eq $True ) { New-ConditionalText -Text Yellow }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is a positive lookahead and lookbehind. Effectivly it gets the text between two characters or sets. Really handy if you have a consistently formatted set of data to work with.

```
[regex]$days_90 = '(?<=y).*?(?=d)'
```

- `.` Matches any characters without line breaks.
- `*` Matches 0 or more of the preceding token.
- `?` Makes the regex lazy and try to match as few as possible.